# Sumar valores de los dias de la semana realtime database

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos de los dias de la semana para obtener el pago de un trabajador.

lo que hace esta función es una CONSULTA POR DÍA, es decir, hace una consulta del día lunes y me devuelve el valor, luego hace la consulta del día martes y devuelve el valor y asi sucesivamente.

lo que quiero hacer es sumar cada valor que me vaya dando y sacar el total de la semana

Gracias de antemano

Comment: pega por favor tu código, no una foto de éste. Estoy muy miope para transcribir eso a mi equipo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define una variable global fuera del `for`, por ejemplo:

> `let total = 0;`

Después, debajo del comentario `//SUMAR PAGO` pon:

> `total += pago;`

En dado caso de que estés recibiendo una cadena de texto en:

> `const pago = snapshot3.val().nomina;`

Usa un parseInt encerrando todo lo que está después del `=`

> `const pago = parseInt(snapshot3.val().nomina);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente, agregué lo siguiente debajo del comentario //SUMAR PAGO para que funcione como yo quiero:                                         
 `const pago=parseInt(snapshot3.val().nomina); 
   cont++;
   total +=pago;
   if (cont==Object.keys(snapshot2.val()).length) {
            console.log(trabajador+"= "+total)
   }`